# Primes of the form .$..55555444433322122333444455555...$

Tags: prime-numbers

What is the smallest  prime number of the form $...55555444433322122333444455555...$, where the concatenation runs through the first natural numbers, and where each decimal number $n$ being repeated/written $n$ times, for example:
$$13131313131313131313131313121212121212121212121212....444433322122333444\\
....12121212121212121212121213131313131313131313131313$$

(Lets call it $n = 13$)

I've checked to $n = 19$. Is there prime number of such form ?

Comment: If there is, $n$ must be of the form $3k+1$ (or your number will be a multiple of $3$).

Comment: What base are you using?

Comment: @barakmanos, I used base 10

Comment: What's so special about $10$ in the context of this question?

Comment: @barakmanos perhaps it is the system we are all most familiar with?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: **In the context of this question**.

Comment: Well in that case $22122_3=233_{10}$ is prime.

Comment: @barakmanos alright, alright, no need to bold at me `._.`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: **hahaha**.

Comment: @barakmanos, Thanks, but here we are interested in base10  : )

Comment: @KazuyaKazunaga: OK, I see you've changed your mind. I personally think that there is nothing interesting in particular with base $10$ in the context of this question, but perhaps somebody will come up with an answer for this specific case.

Comment: n >= 721, with the resulting value at least 1.5 million digits.

Comment: n >= 873, with over 2.2 million digits.  No more searching for me.